# What's a good substitute for gnome terminal?

Tags: terminal, gnome

Lately, I've been opening up several terminals at a time. Having to alt-tab between terminals is confusing.  I need something that combines several terminals in just one window. What are good alternatives?

**Edit**: I don't like tabs. I want consoles **in 2x2 grid arrangement in one window**.

Comment: Since screen did what you wanted, maybe you can update the question to be more focused, such as "How do I run multiple side-by-side shell sessions in a single terminal (screen)?" to help with people searching.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) in your terminal.

[image: Screenshot of GNU screen with vertical and horizontal splits]

To generate this screen shot, I opened a terminal and ran `screen`.  To split the window, I used the keystroke "`ctrl-a S`" for a horizontal split and "`ctrl-a |`" for a vertical split.  To start the additional shells, I ran `screen` three times in the active shell.  To switch between windows, I used the keystroke "`ctrl-a tab`".  To change the shell that was being displayed in the active window ("`0 bash`", "`1 bash`", etc.), I used the keystroke "`ctrl-a n`" ("next") or "`ctrl-a p`" ("previous").  To exit each `screen` process, I just exited the shell running in the `screen` process; doing so four times returned me to my ordinary terminal.

Summary of `screen` keystrokes:

```
ctrl-a S      split the window horizontally
ctrl-a |      split the window vertically
ctrl-a tab    switch to the next window
ctrl-a n      switch to the next process
ctrl-a p      switch to the previous process
```

(edit: jtimberman) If you have a version that supports it, you can do a vertical split of a screen with "ctl-|" (pipe), so you could do 2+ x 2+ screens per terminal. Ubuntu 9.04 has this capability, it was introduced ~version 4.00.03.

(edit: las3rjock) The screenshot has been updated to show `screen` with vertical as well as horizontal splits.  Since the version of `screen` that comes with Mac OS X does not come with this feature, I built it from CVS according to [directions I found on this blog](http://writequit.org/blog/?p=183).  I assume you could do the same for Linux by skipping the `patch` steps.

Comment: Can it have 4 terminals in a 2x2 grid arrangement?

Comment: @Randell see my edit to this answer :-)

Comment: @las3rjock, I'm not familiar with those keystrokes. How do you perform that?

Comment: I can't seem to split the regions.

Comment: What I really hate about me and screen is that I am able to remember how to split, but I'm never able to remeber how to unsplit.

Comment: @Manni Apparently the keystroke to unsplit is "ctrl-a Q"

Comment: How to I do "ctrl-a S"? I'm not used to having commands like that. o I have to press shift to get the uppercase S? Is there a pause between ctrl-a S? And why is it ctrl-a instead of ctrl+a?

Comment: I got it now. So I have to shift+S.

Comment: Awesome. This is just what I need.

Comment: las3rjock: thanks. How am I supposed to get that into my poor head?

Comment: I have never been able to use vertical splitting in screen consistently across platforms which is a deal breaker for me. [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) is an awesome alternative that provides the same functionality and "just works".

Answer (score 17):

I think you might be interested in [Terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/terminator/) :D

**Overview**

The goal of this project is to produce a useful tool for arranging terminals.
It is inspired by programs such as gnome-multi-term, quadkonsole, etc. in that the main focus is arranging terminals in grids (tabs is the most common default method, which Terminator also supports).

Much of the behaviour of Terminator is based on GNOME Terminal, and we are adding more features from that as time goes by, but we also want to extend out in different directions with useful features for sysadmins and other users. If you have any suggestions, please file wishlist bugs! (see below for the address)

**Features:**

- List item
- Arrange terminals in a grid
- Tabs
- Drag and drop re-ordering of terminals
- Lots of keyboard shortcuts
- Config file to override gnome-terminal settings
- Simultaneous typing to arbitrary groups of terminals

[image: terminator screenshot]

[image: terminator screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

Please look at my [blog](http://blog.tbits.ie/2010/05/terminal-multiplexer/) entry about tmux found here... That is way more powerful than screen, in short, the config file in the attached blog entry re-configures the tmux shortcut keystrokes to simulate screen, originally tmux uses the Ctrl+B combination in order to not to confuse screen utility. And the keys are reconfigured so... instead of Ctrl+B, Ctrl+A is used:

- Ctrl+A for initiating a tmux attention keystroke, such as ? for list of keys,
- Ctrl+A, Ctrl+A to flick between different windows,
- Ctrl+A, 1 for first window, Ctrl+A, 2 for second window and so on
- Ctrl+A, Tab to switch focus between split windows within one session
- Ctrl+A, C to bring up a new bash shell

Read it and learn it... :)

Comment: your blog is no longa alive!

Answer (score 4):

Konsole is the best, multitabs and some other cool stuff.

Comment: Apparently Konsole has a split view which does what you want: http://kdemonkey.blogspot.com/2007/01/introductions-and-future-of-konsole.html  Here is a screenshot: http://www.robertknight.me.uk/files/kde/konsole-split-view-1.png

Comment: It is trivial to embed NxM konsole kparts in a single app. I've seen such an app, but can't recall the name.

Answer (score 3):

I have used:

- [eterm](http://eterm.org) - Enlightened Terminal Emulator
- [mrxvt](http://code.google.com/p/mrxvt/) - lightweight multi-tabbed X terminal emulator

Both are pretty nice.

Though I still prefer gnome-terminal with tabs :-).

Comment: Can use Ctrl+Shift+T to open new tab, Ctrl+PageUp to go to previous tab, and Ctrl+PageDn to go to next tab.

Comment: Yeah apparently the OP doesn't want to use tabs, so I removed the bulk of the gnome-terminal info.

Answer (score 3):

If the current answers don't give you the flexibility or feeling that you want you may also want to have a look at tiling window managers. This ofc is a big change just for tiling terminals but if you are planning on doing the majority of things in tiled terminals a tiled WM may have benefits over the other solutions.

I'd personally recommend [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/)

Answer (score 2):

you could use  [splitvt](http://www.devolution.com/~slouken/projects/splitvt/)  to split ANY terminal window in two - one above the other, not side-by-side.

However, while it is possible to split the terminal horizontally or vertically (or both) in some terminal emulators or in screen, you are limited to 2 or 3 or perhaps 4 side-by-side before they become too narrow (or short) to be of any use. IMO, tabbed terms combined with a program like xttitle to set the tab title is a lot less confusing and a lot more useful. YMMV.

other people have already mentioned screen as well as eterm and  mrxvt and others, so i'll point out a feature of gnome-terminal that you might have missed.

you do realise that you don't have to alt-tab between terminals in gnome-terminal, don't you?

if you're using tabbed terminals, you can use Alt-1, Alt-2, Alt-3 etc to switch between the terminals.

BTW, i mostly use mrxvt as my terminal of choice - but gnome-terminal is installed by default on most linux systems so i've got used to how it works.  i prefer mrxvt but GT is OK or good enough for light/casual use.

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer Xterm with [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/), which you can configure to split the terminal. See the [tmux manpage](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1)

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for helping with this question. The site standards have changed in the six years since this question was originally posted. The question would now be considered off-topic, and answers that recommend software are now expected to be a bit more rigorous. It's hard to hold you to a different standard than other answers on the same question, but the accepted answer is a good example of what would now be considered a good one (look at the upvotes on the two highest rated answers). For guidance, see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers